# How to add AsyncTask Timeout in this code?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I launch an AsyncTask in mainActivity [Get_IO()]:

```
   // Rafraichissmeent de l'activity
    refresh = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            // Do something
            new Get_IO().execute();
            handler.postDelayed(refresh, 10000);
        }
    };
    handler.post(refresh);
```

But due to not having a good connection quality, the Task is still waiting, i want to add a timeout, but how?
I've tried adding another Task to do the time out, but unfortunately, it's not working.

Here's the Get_IO() code:

```
public class Get_IO extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        //Handler mHandler = new Handler();
        //Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        //    @Override
        //    public void run() {
        //        if (mAT.getStatus() == Status.RUNNING || mAT.getStatus() == Status.PENDING) {
        //            mAT.cancel(true); //Cancel Async task or do the operation you want after 1 minute
        //        }
        //    }
        //};
        //mHandler.postDelayed(runnable, 60000);

        // Showing progress dialog
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(PortailActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        // Creating service handler class instance
        ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();

        // Making a request to url and getting response
        String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url_status, ServiceHandler.GET);

        Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);

        if (jsonStr != null) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                string_input = jsonObj.getString(TAG_INPUT);
                string_output = jsonObj.getString(TAG_OUTPUT);

                // tmp hashmap for single contact
                HashMap<String, String> iostatus = new HashMap<String, String>();

                // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                iostatus.put(TAG_INPUT, string_input);
                iostatus.put(TAG_OUTPUT, string_output);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        // Dismiss the progress dialog
        if (pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.dismiss();

        TextView lblMobile = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mobile_label);
        lblMobile.setText(string_input.concat(" - ") .concat(string_output));
        check_etat_portail();
    }
}
```

I don't understand the thing very well  ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to start new activity when `makeServiceCall()` is executed, you should do this in `onPostExecute()` with the check if `makeServiceCall()` was suscessful. And if you want to shorten network timeout, you should set it for your HTTP request (so basically at least in `makeServiceCall()` or even lower, depending on your app strcuture.